# I am trying to run this code in all sheets except one in the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal ws As Range)

        Dim rInt As Range
        Dim rCell As Range

        Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B32, B37:B45, K3:K11, K12:K18"))
        If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
            For Each rCell In rInt
                rCell.Value = "1"
            Next
        End If
        Set rInt = Nothing
        Set rCell = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Place the code in the worksheet code area of all the sheets you have except the one sheet you want to avoid.

[image]

Comment: I felt the urge to spice-up your answer a bit. I sure hope you don't mind. Feel free to remove the picture and down-vote some of my posts as a mean of punishment for unwanted behavior (if you don't want / like that).

Comment: @Ralph  **Thank you for the help.**  The edit is an improvement. I like the animation.  I wish I knew how to do it.

Comment: @Ralph  Thanks for the info !

Comment: @Ralph  Delete any time you like.

Comment: Would I be able to automate this process - so when a new workbook is created it automatically applies the code in that workbook?

Comment: @aakashlimbu  You could create the new workbook by copying an existing workbook that already contains the macros you require.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Workbook-level event (code goes in the `ThisWorkbook` module)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Const NOT_THIS_ONE As String = "Tester" '<< sheet to skip
    Dim rInt As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    If Sh.Name = NOT_THIS_ONE Then Exit Sub

    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B32, B37:B45, K3:K11, K12:K18"))
    If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each rCell In rInt
            rCell.Value = "1"
        Next
    End If

    Set rInt = Nothing
    Set rCell = Nothing

End Sub
```